# mongoose populate return empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose, currently i got 2 schema  first one is product detail and the second one is inventory both schema are in seperate files

ProductDetail Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productDetailSchema = new Schema({
    ProductID:{type:String,unique:true, require:true},
    ProductName:{type:String, require:true},
    Spec:String,
    Price:String,
    Unit:String,
    OwnBrand:Boolean,
    Inventory:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'inventoryModel'}
}, {collection:'products'});


module.exports = mongoose.model('productDetailModel', productDetailSchema)
```

Inventory Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var inventorySchema = new Schema({
    product:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'productDetailModel' },
    stockLevel:Number
}, {collection:'inventory'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('inventoryModel', inventorySchema)
```

In this case I would want to put the inventory stockLevel in to productDetail. Like this

```
{
    ProductID:'P701',
    ProductName:'popcorn',
    Spec:'Large Pack',
    Price:'10.00',
    Unit:'packs'
    Inventory: 20
}
```

Therefore I've try to use the mongoose populate method

```
productDetail.findOne({ProductID:'P701'}).populate('Inventory').exec(function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log(doc)
    }
})
```

This is the data that i've in my "Inventory collection"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584f663d95dfa29bad337572"),
    "ProductID": "P701",
    "StockLevel": "20"
}
```

and the data in "ProductDetail Collection"

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("584a3cea027c1f62da941acf"),
    ProductID:'P701',
    ProductName:'popcorn',
    Spec:'Large Pack',
    Price:'10.00',
    Unit:'packs'
}
```

For some reason there are no error shows up but the console.log(doc) still didnt include any Inventory: stockLevel. I know I'm doing something wrong, but i've no idea where it is. What kind of key concept i'm missing inorder for this code to work?  Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show how exactly are you saving `inventoryModel` _id in the `productDetailModel`?

Comment: Will you please post the content in productDetail of ProductId: 'P701'? It seems like you are storing invalid inventory refId while saving the product detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `inventory` in the `productDetailModel` should be an `ObjectId`, from what you have shown here is a number(i.e. 20).

```
{
    ProductID:'P701',
    ProductName:'popcorn',
    Spec:'Large Pack',
    Price:'10.00',
    Unit:'packs'
    Inventory: 20
}
```

this should be like this:

```
Inventory : ObjectId('someId');
```

That's why it is not populating, because it can't find an `ObjectId` as 20 in the `inventoryModel`.

**EDIT**

This `productDetail` document has no field as `inventory`. Thus, it is not able to populate it.

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("584a3cea027c1f62da941acf"),
    ProductID:'P701',
    ProductName:'popcorn',
    Spec:'Large Pack',
    Price:'10.00',
    Unit:'packs'
}
```

It should have something like this too:

```
inventory :  ObjectId("584f663d95dfa29bad337572");//some `ObjectId` which corresponds to `inventoryModel` document.
```

You need to **create inventory `field`  and save ObjectId of some inventory document** in `productDetail` document while saving it, or may be while updating it.

Comment: Hi Ravi  i've update the data on the question above, is that what you need?

Comment: Hi Ravi This is now finally working properly! Thank you so much for the help.  :D

Comment: I am glad, i could help.